# Fire-Animation export to gltf (Domain visible)

Tags: animation

I have created a fire animation which I can also render.

Unfortunately when exporting to gltf the domain solid is visible.

Is there any way to export this fire animation to gltf / glb to use it e.g. in three.js ?

I attach my export settings as a screenshot.

[[image: Export-Settings+GLTF-Viewerenter image description here][1]]

Comment: You mention domain, i guess you mean you made a fire simulation? I don't think gltf supports that. That would be the job of VDB.

Answer (score -1):

try selecting the fire first with its baked animation and on export, click on "selected objects" under "limit to"